# The import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.Initializer cannot be resolved in solr search

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, solr

Creating the program solr search with eclipse and hibernate.
I have used the below dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have imported `import org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer;` but I am Getting error as CoreContainer.Initializer cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: I'm not sure CoreContainer.Initializer is available in 5.4.0: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/core/CoreContainer.html. The latest version I see it for is 4.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this class has been removed the new versions of Apache Solr. this inner class is not available within version 5.3.1 - http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-core/allclasses-noframe.html

whereas its available within version 4.2 - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-core/allclasses-noframe.html

Make sure you are using the correct version.